# ¿Como quito el mi dominio cuando abro una url externa?

Tags: angular, linux, apache

Estoy desarrollando un sitio web en angular en el cual tengo una opción para abrir una url externa a mi sitio (ej: https://stackoverflow.com) en otra pestaña.

Probando en desarrollo funciona bien, el problema sale cuando lo publico un servidor lunix con apache, me coloca la ruta de mi dominio por delante (Ej. www.midomio.com/https://stackoverflow.com),:

```
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com" target="_blank">https://stackoverflow.com</a>
```

Resultado esperado re dirección a

```
https://stackoverflow.com
```

Resultado

```
http://www.midomio.com/https://stackoverflow.com
```

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y, de paso, ganar tu primera medalla. También es importante que leas [ask] y [mcve] para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad, de esta manera favoreces a que los usuarios las respondan y te ayuden

Comment: ¿Podrías aportar todo el código relevante?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una posible solución es hacerlo de la siguiente manera.

html:

```
<a (click)="openPage()">https://stackoverflow.com</a>
```

ts:

```
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';
...
constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: any) { }

openPage(): void {
    this.document.location.href = 'https://stackoverflow.com';
}
```

Basado en [How to redirect to an external URL in Angular2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34338440/how-to-redirect-to-an-external-url-in-angular2)

Comment: No me resulto, ahora hace lo mismo, solo que en la misma pestaña.

Comment: Cambie el código.

Comment: Gracias, resulto esta vez

Comment: @thebart0 recuerda aceptar la respuesta si soluciono el problema